# FSM: Can't see output in waveform

Tags: system-verilog, register-transfer-level

I have created a finite state machine/datapath which I am debugging in ModelSim. The states are Load, Increment, and Finish. The states seem to be progressing fine, however countx and county (internal signals) are not being incremented in the increment state, and consequently vga_x, vga_y outputs are not being assigned.

I tried changing the countx and county signals from logic to reg but that didn't make any difference.  also tried setting the output signals to blocking, since I want countx and county assigned to the output after they are incremented in the same state.

```
module fillscreen(input logic clk, input logic rst_n, input logic [2:0] colour,
              input logic start, output logic done,
              output logic [7:0] vga_x, output logic [6:0] vga_y,
              output logic [2:0] vga_colour, output logic vga_plot);

 enum logic [1:0] {Load = 2'b00, Increment = 2'b01, Out = 2'b10, Finish = 2'b11} state, next_state;
 reg[7:0] countx;
 reg [6:0] county;

 always @ (posedge clk) begin
    state = Load;
    case(state)

    Load: begin
           if(rst_n == 0) 
            next_state <= Load; 
        else if (start == 1) 
            next_state <= Increment;
        else begin
        next_state <= Load; end
    //initialize counter
    countx <= 0;    
    county <= 0; end

    Increment: begin
        if(rst_n == 0) 
            next_state <= Load;
        else if (county < 119 && countx < 159) begin
            county <= county+1; 
            next_state <= Increment; end                
        else if (countx < 159) begin
            countx <= countx +1;
            next_state <= Increment; end
        else begin 
            next_state <= Finish;end
    //output            
    vga_y = county;
    vga_x = countx;
    vga_colour = countx % 8;            
    vga_plot = 1;
    end
    Finish: begin
        done <= 1;          
        if(rst_n == 0) 
            next_state <= Load; 
        else begin
            next_state <= Finish; end
    end
    default: begin 
        vga_y = county;
        vga_x = countx;
        done = 0;
        vga_plot = 0;
    end
    endcase
    state = next_state;
end  
endmodule
```

Answer (score 2):

notice that always block is evaluated procedurally from begin to end.
the first line you have is

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
state = Load;
...
```

This set the state to "Load" when the block executes and erases the previous set state from

```
state = next_state;
```

This mean every clock cycle, case(state) block will go down the Load path.

I suggest the FSM state is set in its own always block to simplify the code.

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
    if(!rst_n) begin
        state <= Load;
    end
    else begin
        state <= next_state;
    end
end
```

this way, you can focus on using "state" as an input and "next_state" as an output of your original always block.